# Assigning Roles in AspNetUserRoles table made by Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity, roles

I don't really understand how to work with this Identity thing, below I tried my best, I don't have errors but its doing nothing and I wonder why.
I also checked this:

[Adding Role dynamically in new VS 2013 Identity UserManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543198/adding-role-dynamically-in-new-vs-2013-identity-usermanager?lq=1)

[Add User to Role ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689183/add-user-to-role-asp-net-identity?lq=1)

Table in database is modified I have: Id (auto-increment, Primary Key), RoleId, UserId - both by default and without Primary Key.

```
 protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);  
        var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

        var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = CreateUserWizard1.UserName };
        var role = new IdentityRole { Id = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue};

        //Create new user and try to store in DB.

        if (CreateUserWizard1.Password.ToString() == CreateUserWizard1.ConfirmPassword.ToString())
        {
            try
            {
                IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, CreateUserWizard1.Password.ToString());
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {   

                    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                    var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                    var selectedRole = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

                    var currentUser = manager.FindByName(user.UserName);
                    var roleResult = manager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, selectedRole);

                    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties(), userIdentity);
                    .
                    .
```

I am not looking for classic solution made with visual studio. I have user profiles with SQL and are working fine, but my roles are now messed up. They are working fine if I put manually in that SQL table RoleId and UserId thought.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the other [UserStore Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn272146(v=vs.108).aspx) and the other [RoleStore Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457120(v=vs.108).aspx).

They are both accepting the database context as parameters.

In both links you provided the constructor with parameter is used.

Comment: I will check as soon as I can, but explain me briefly... are those a class with method I have to write? I am very confused because I can create Users without anything as above. And I am more confused because I found on internet a lot of examples with MVC and I don't use MVC. I started with Asp.net Empty Application. I will check those two thought and I will edit code later if with solution or another problems. Thank you.