# Role based authentivation in ASP.NET core MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3, role-based-access-control

I have searched for some hours now and can't figure out how to set up a role based authentication in asp.NET core MVC 6 using identity 3.

I have worked my way trough these threads:

[Adding Role dynamically in new VS 2013 Identity UserManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543198/adding-role-dynamically-in-new-vs-2013-identity-usermanager)

[Creating Roles in Asp.net Identity MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697226/creating-roles-in-asp-net-identity-mvc-5)

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc

But I can't figure out how to get a similar role-based authentication to work in asp.NET core.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone knows how to use the RoleManager correctly and how to seed an admin account in the database. Hope you can help me out with further material.

Sincerly Promos